# Why doesn't this simple Knockout.js example work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am playing around with Knockout.js and created this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/JcTxT/30/

```
<div id="term_grp" data-role="fieldcontain"><a>Semester:</a>

<fieldset id="term_fields" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <input type="radio" name="term" id="ss" value="ss" data-bind="checked: term" />
    <label for="ss">Sommersemester</label>
    <input type="radio" name="term" id="ws" value="ws" data-bind="checked: term" />
    <label for="ws">Wintersemester</label>
</fieldset>
Term is <span data-bind="text: pommes"></span>
```

```
var aResult = {
    term: ko.observable("ss"),
    pommes: "TEST"
};

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#mainPage', function () {
    ko.applyBindings(aResult);
});
```

I expected one of the radio button to be checked (the one with the value "ss" but this is not the case. Does anyone know, why?

Cheers

Comment: jQuery Mobile is the source of your problem. It changes the dom which can mess up the bindings. You radio button is bound, but jQuery Mobile hides it and inserts a div and a span which aren't bound.

Comment: OK, are their binding frameworks that do york with jQUery Mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, what needs to be done?

Add another event handler and add it to the binding:

```
var aResult = {
    term: ko.observable("ws"),
    pommes: "TEST2"
};

ko.bindingHandlers.mobileradio = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {},
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
        if (valueUnwrapped == $(element).val()) {
            $(element).prop("checked", "true").checkboxradio("refresh");
        } else {
            $(element).removeProp("checked").checkboxradio("refresh");
        }
    }
};

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(aResult);
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JcTxT/35/

Answer (score 5):

It works, if you use:

    `$(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(aResult);
    });`

And turn off jquery mobile.

I tried in your jsfiddle.

If you need jquery mobile, this link works:
http://www.codesizzle.com/jquery-mobile-radio-with-knockout-js/

Comment: Added a note about jquery mobile